# Code first self referencing foreign key (more than one)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, code-first

I have a User-Entity which has the EntityBase as parent class. 
The parent class looks like this:

```
public class EntityBase
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public bool? IsPublic { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }

        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Guid? CreatedById { get; set; }

        public virtual User UpdatedBy  { get; set; }
        public Guid? UpdatedById { get; set; }

        public virtual User DeletedBy { get; set; }
        public Guid? DeletedById { get; set; }
    }
```

The User class:

```
public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastAction { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cocktail> Cocktails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Drink> DrinkVotes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cocktail> CocktailVotes { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have problems with the self referencing because there is a circular dependency, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your base entity have to be abstract

```
   public abstract class EntityBase ....
```

2) Move the Id in the child classes for example UserId/CoktailId etc (Optional but recommended)

4) Use InverseProperty Attribute to reference the  Cocktails
   example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: You can leave it on the base class and you have to configure it manually. Think about the use Case :EntityA inherit from Baseclass and EntityB inherit  from EntityA? the Id in base class will be used for EntityA or EntityB. believe me alot of other use cases it will make for you a headache, my recommendtion for you was just keep it simple and move it down.

Comment: second use case think if you want to create a relationship one-to-one what you gona do ? your Id have to be !!! DatabaseGeneratedOption.None !!!! so you have again to use trick to solve the problem

Comment: Yes I see, I think I move the foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

In your context, you need to override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder) and then setup the relationship like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.UpdatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.DeletedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

You are removing the circular references here by

1. Stating the CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, and DeletedBy relationships are optional
2. Disabling cascade on delete