# default constructor for POCO entity in EF6 Code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new in EF. 
I'm making an app with EF6 Code First approach, I've made all my POCO entities to derive from a base class which define an Id.
What I don't know is how to declare the constructor for an entity that handles many to many relatioship.
For example:

I've got this entity:

```
 public partial class ArqAppRole
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        public DateTime SinceDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UntilDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ArqApplication ArqApplication { get; set; }

        public virtual ArqRole ArqRole { get; set; }
    }
```

this was auto-generated by EF, what I want is to set it superclass to BaseEntity class that has a default constructor which sets it Id and I don't know how to handle ArqApplication and ArqRole properties and their propper Ids

My base class is:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        private object _id;

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public object Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            protected set
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }

        protected BaseEntity() : this(null) { }

        protected BaseEntity(object id)
        {
            _id = id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the Id on the base class and in this use case you have to configure your one-to-one releshinship with Fluent API.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<ArqAppRole>()
              .HasRequired(s => s.Application) 
              .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.ArqAppRole); 
}
```

Fluent API will override your code first. But putting the Id in the base class is a bad practice and you have to find tricks everywhere. Just use the conventional way and use the EF as should be used.

More info: [Code first self referencing foreign key (more than one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829442/code-first-self-referencing-foreign-key-more-than-one/37829987#37829987)